# push_back vs emplace_back when using template type instance as value

Tags: c++

I'm aware of the difference between `emplace_back()`, which constructs object in-place given constructor parameters, and `push_back()` which copies existing value.  Thus `emplace_back(a, b, c)` is preferable over `push_back(Type(a, b, c))` as the latter results in contruction and then copy, while the former constructs in-place and thus need not copy.

But, is there a difference between `emplace_back()` and `push_back()` if I already have an instance?  E.g. consider the following code:

```cpp
MyType resource = get_resource();
std::vector<MyType> a;
a.emplace_back(resource);
a.push_back(resource);
```

If I understand it right, in the above example, `emplace_back()` would construct the copy in-place by allocating and then invoking the constructor passing in `resource`, which effectively invokes the copy-constructor.  And calling `push_back()` would effectively be the same thing?  <strike>Or, would `push_back()` result in first, a default instance being created using the default constructor, then it overwrites via copy assignment to copy the provided value?</strike>

If so, then is there really ever a reason to use `push_back()` and instead always do `emplace_back()` <strike>to write existing instances in by directly invoking the copy constructor and skipping default initialization altogether</strike> as it covers greater range of use-cases?

Comment: they are the same for rvalues of the element type

Comment: Indeed, there's no difference in this case. It's possible that, had `std::vector` been designed today, it'd only have `emplace_back` method and no `push_back`.

Comment: There's no such thing as "overwritten via copy constructor". It wouldn't be valid to construct the same instance twice. Besides, `std::vector<T>` works with types `T` that don't have a default constructor to begin with, so `push_back` can't do what you describe even if it wanted to.

Comment: Don't you want to `std::move(resource)` instead of copying it?

Comment: @NathanOliver -- thank you for clarifying that it's effectively the same thing (for rvalue).  That's what I was confused about and trying to understand (question came up in a code review and causeed some doubts).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik -- yeah, agree if it's the same thing, `push_back` no longer seems to cary any benefit other than backward compatibility.  Re: "overwritten" part -- you're correct, I was, for some odd reason, at that moment thinking about pre-sized vector that would default-init items, and not the actual case I was describing, so definitely a brainfart on my part.  I'm striking thru that part of question to remove confusion for others.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using C++ 11 or higher? The impl of the two are like:

```cpp
void push_back(_Tp&& __x) {
  emplace_back(std::move(__x));
}

void push_back(const _Tp& __x) {
  if (this->_M_impl._M_finish != this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage) {
    _GLIBCXX_ASAN_ANNOTATE_GROW(1);
    _Alloc_traits::construct(this->_M_impl, this->_M_impl._M_finish, __x);
    ++this->_M_impl._M_finish;
    _GLIBCXX_ASAN_ANNOTATE_GREW(1);
  } else {
    _M_realloc_insert(end(), __x);
  }
}

template<typename... _Args>
void emplace_back(_Args&&... __args) {
  if (this->_M_impl._M_finish != this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage) {
    _GLIBCXX_ASAN_ANNOTATE_GROW(1);
    _Alloc_traits::construct(this->_M_impl, this->_M_impl._M_finish, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
    ++this->_M_impl._M_finish;
    _GLIBCXX_ASAN_ANNOTATE_GREW(1);
  } else {
    _M_realloc_insert(end(), std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
  }
}
```

The cost gap between them is equivalent to the cost gap between `std::move` and `std::forward`.